# magento ui component multiselect xml

Tags: magento, magento2

I can not understand why the error

> Could not save the brand: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\2016\mercury_61189_222_007\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228

on the idea of all done right, here is the code of the module

```
<field name="website_id_2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Collection</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Website 2</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">website_id_2</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Can someone know the nuances?

Answer (score 2):

I decided my question.
It was necessary for the save function to execute () to write 2 lines to preserve the array

```
$data['website_id_2']=implode(',',$data['website_id_2']);
$model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```